# How to generate Radio Buttons With Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I googled for it but I couldn't find it out also I couldn't find any resource for it or tutorials ,
I wanna make it sure if each and every controls can be populated mvc scaffolding or not.
I am a beginner in mvc any help is appreciated.

I guess it would be possible to generate every control in some way and 
it generated a weird control for byte Datatype

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Active must be a number." data-val-required="The Active field is required." id="Active" name="Active" type="number" value="">
```

Comment: In my view Scaffolding generating control based on strongly type like class.

Comment: but i dont know what datatype should be used for which controls,like ritch text box,radiobuttons,radiobuttonlist,checkboxlist etc.

Comment: @nichu09 this article is not about any Scaffolding